# Send request with auth token in header in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, spring, jwt

I implemented jwt stateless in backend , so except login and signup all other method has to intercept in angularjs and sending auth token to server in request header .But token is not sending mean not seeing in reqest header in console(developer tools).

This is my interceptor.js :

```
/**
 * 
 */
/* Interceptor declaration */
rootApp.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $sessionStorage, $location,$window) {
    return {
        request: function (config) {
            //config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if ($window.sessionStorage.token) {
                config.headers.Authorization =  'Bearer '  + $window.sessionStorage.token;
                //config.headers['x-auth-token'] ='Bearer '  + $window.sessionStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
        },
        response: function (response) {

            if(response.status === 200){                
                if(response.data && response.data.success === false){
                    if($rootScope.authFailureReasons.indexOf(response.data.reason) !== -1){
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                }
            }

            if (response.status === 401) {
                $location.path('/');
            }

            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        'responseError': function (rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});

rootApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
      // $httpProvider.interceptors.push('headerInterceptor');
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
    }]);
```

And service.js file is:

```
rootApp.service('adminService', function ($rootScope, $http, $q,$window) {

    return {
        inviteUser: function (user) {

            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url:$rootScope.baseUrl+'api/v1/admin/user/add',
                data:user


            }).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {



                deferred.resolve(response);
            }).error(function () {
                // Something went wrong.
                deferred.reject({'success': false, 'msg': 'Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.'});
            });

            return deferred.promise;

        }
    };
});
```

In server side X-AUTH-TOKEN is allowed in headers too.Where i am going wrong 
Please help.

Comment: are you sure `if ($window.sessionStorage.token)` is evaluating to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

hey I have recently made my first token authentication in my Ionic app .. yeah it is an easy step but implementation may take some time if you are not a language PRO.. 
you can try this.
https://devdactic.com/user-auth-angularjs-ionic/
this is one of the finest and tested tutorial on the web for token based AUTH..
Maybe that may help you to find the error !